# JasperPHP with Laravel 5.3 Output file not saved in disk

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using code like this

```
use JasperPHP\JasperPHP as JasperPHP;
$jasper = new JasperPHP;
// Process a Jasper file to PDF and RTF (you can use directly the .jrxml)
 $database = Config::get('database.connections.mysql');
 $output = public_path() . '/report/'.time().'_codelution';
 $file = base_path() .'/storage/reporting/hrm_plan_formation.pdf';
 $ext = "pdf";

$bb = $jasper->process(
    __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/cossou/jasperphp/examples/hello_world.jasper',
    $output,
    array("pdf", "rtf"),
    array("php_version" => "7.2")
)->output();
```

print_r($bb);

Output showing like this:

C:^^^\xampp^^^\htdocs^^^\Sites^^^\laravel53^^^\vendor^^^\cossou^^^\jasperphp^^^\src^^^\JasperPHP/../JasperStarter/bin/jasperstarter process C:^^^\xampp^^^\htdocs^^^\Sites^^^\laravel53^^^\routes/../../vendor/cossou/jasperphp/examples/hello_world.jasper -o C:^^^\xampp^^^\htdocs^^^\Sites^^^\laravel53^^^\public/report/1479887883_codelution -f pdf rtf -r C:^^^\xampp^^^\htdocs^^^\Sites^^^\laravel53^^^\vendor^^^\cossou^^^\jasperphp^^^\src^^^\JasperPHP/../../../../../ -P php_version=7.2

But File not saved in disk.

Comment: You have defined the parameters `$database`, `$file`, and `$ext`, but haven't passed them to the `$jasper->process( )` method call.